# Refresh Target of all bindings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am having a bit of difficulty in a CRUD form. We have a button which saves the form and has the IsDefault flag set to true, so that the user can press enter at any point to save the form.

The problem is that when the user is typing in a textbox and hits the enter key the source of the textbox binding isn't updated. I know that this is because the default `UpdateSourceTrigger` functionality for textboxes is `LostFocus`, which I've used to overcome the problem is some cases, but this actually causes more problems in other cases.

For standard `string` fields this is fine, however for things like `double`s and `int`s the validation occurs on property change, and so stop the user from typing say `1.5` into a textbox that is bound to a double source (they can type 1, but the validation stops the decimal, they could type `15` then move the cursor back and press `.` though).

Is there a better way to approach this? I looked at ways to refresh all bindings in the window in code which came up with firing a `PropertyChanged` event with `string.empty` however this only refreshes the target, not the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My standard solution when I don't want to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the bindings is to use a custom `AttachedProperty` that when set to true will will update the source of the binding when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.

Here's a copy of my Attached Property

```
// When set to True, Enter Key will update Source
#region EnterUpdatesTextSource DependencyProperty

// Property to determine if the Enter key should update the source. Default is False
public static readonly DependencyProperty EnterUpdatesTextSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EnterUpdatesTextSource", typeof (bool),
                                        typeof (TextBoxHelper),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(false, EnterUpdatesTextSourcePropertyChanged));

// Get
public static bool GetEnterUpdatesTextSource(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (bool) obj.GetValue(EnterUpdatesTextSourceProperty);
}

// Set
public static void SetEnterUpdatesTextSource(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
{
    obj.SetValue(EnterUpdatesTextSourceProperty, value);
}

// Changed Event - Attach PreviewKeyDown handler
private static void EnterUpdatesTextSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj,
                                                          DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var sender = obj as UIElement;
    if (obj != null)
    {
        if ((bool) e.NewValue)
        {
            sender.PreviewKeyDown += OnPreviewKeyDownUpdateSourceIfEnter;
        }
        else
        {
            sender.PreviewKeyDown -= OnPreviewKeyDownUpdateSourceIfEnter;
        }
    }
}

// If key being pressed is the Enter key, and EnterUpdatesTextSource is set to true, then update source for Text property
private static void OnPreviewKeyDownUpdateSourceIfEnter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        if (GetEnterUpdatesTextSource((DependencyObject) sender))
        {
            var obj = sender as UIElement;
            BindingExpression textBinding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(
                obj, TextBox.TextProperty);

            if (textBinding != null)
                textBinding.UpdateSource();
        }
    }
}

#endregion //EnterUpdatesTextSource DependencyProperty
```

And it's used like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText}" local:EnterUpdatesTextSource="True" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update binding source by using the following code:

```
textBox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

Comment: Strange, in my tests the LostFocus event wasn't firing and so the Source wasn't being updated before the Save button's event fired. I'll retest.

Comment: I rechecked. You're right, LostFocus not called. Source update happens after I call Close(). I fixed my answer, but part of it remains relevant.